# Return array elements that are subset of the input array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have such structure in MongoDB:

```
{'key': [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ], [ 1, 2, 6 ], [ 2 ] ] }
```

I need to get arrays which will be a subset or equal to the input array.

For example if the input array is `[1, 2, 6]` it should return `[[1,2,6], [2]]`.

Is there some "good" way to do this? Basically as I understand I need invert operator to `$all`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can actually filter our array to return only those elements that are the intersection of the input array by [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)ing our documents with the aggregation framework.

Starting from MongoDB 3.2 we can use the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator to "select" only the element in the array that satisfy our condition.

The condition here is [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) which return true when the element in the array is a subset of our input array.

```
let inputArray = [1, 2, 6];
db.coll.aggregate(
    [
        { "$project": { 
            "key": { 
                "$filter": { 
                    "input": "$key", 
                    "as": "k", 
                    "cond": { "$setIsSubset": [ "$$k", inputArray ] }
                }
            }
        }}
    ]
)
```

In previous version, we need to use the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator to "filter out" the elements in the array that do not satisfy our condition. In the *"in" expression*, we need to use a logical [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)ition processing to "keep" the element when the condition is true and "replace" the element by `false` when the condition expression evaluates to `false`.

The [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) operator performs a [relative complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)) of `$map`'s result and `[false]`. It worth mentioning that `$setDifference` is fine as long as the data being filtered is "unique".

```
var inputArray = [1, 2, 6];
db.coll.aggregate(
    [
        { "$project": {
            "key": { 
                "$setDifference": [
                    { "$map": { 
                        "input": "$key",
                        "as": "k",
                        "in": { 
                            "$cond": [
                                { "$setIsSubset": [ "$$k", inputArray ] },
                                "$$k",
                                false
                            ]
                         }
                    }},
                    [false]
                ]
            }
        }}
    ]
)
```

Comment: thanks, it works
one comment you have extra curly brackets for value in "key" key for precious version   :)

Comment: @NikolaiYakovlev  that *curly bracket* thing when you ship without testing. thanks;)